# MySQL COUNT() посчитать для каждого товара количество отзывов с конкретным статусом

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Есть таблица с товарами `products(id,title,...)` и есть таблица с отзывами к товарам `reviews(id,product_id,status_id,...)`, надо посчитать для каждого товара количество отзывов со статусом 2(опубликован) ОДНИМ ЗАПРОСОМ.
Пытался так:

```
SELECT COUNT(reviews.product_id) AS count, products.* 
FROM reviews
RIGHT JOIN products ON products.id = reviews.product_id 
GROUP BY products.id
```

выводит количество всех имеющихся комментариев (надо со статусом 2) для каждого товара

```
SELECT COUNT(reviews.product_id) AS count, products.* 
FROM reviews
RIGHT JOIN products ON products.id = reviews.product_id 
WHERE reviews.status_id = 2 GROUP BY products.id
```

добавив `WHERE reviews.status_id = 2`, выводятся только те товары, у которых есть хотя бы один опубликованный отзыв, а надо чтобы все товары попали в этот запрос.

Можно конечно при добавлении товара сразу добавлять к нему 1 опубликованный отзыв, но хотелось бы более адекватный способ

Answer (score 1):

Используйте условное агрегирование. Запрос

```
SELECT {columnset}, COUNT(*)
FROM {tableset}
WHERE {condition}
[GROUP BY {expression}]
```

эквивалентен запросу

```
SELECT {columnset}, SUM({condition})
FROM {tableset}
[GROUP BY {expression}]
```

Но, в отличие от первой формы, во второй можно сразу, в одном запросе, посчитать несколько SUM() с различными {condition}.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.id, COUNT(r.status_id = 2 OR NULL) AS countTwoStatus 
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN reviews AS r ON p.id = r.product_id 
GROUP BY p.id
```

1. совет: лучше не использовать RIGHT JOIN без острой необходимости,
   ведь чаще всего можно переписать его на LEFT, который гораздо лучше
   читается.
2. совет: псевдонимы(AS) так же повышают читаемость,
   рекомендую